# Zero set of polynomials in two variables over complex field contain a non-trivial connected subset?

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials, metric-spaces, connectedness

Let  $f \in \mathbb C[x,y]$ be an irreducible polynomial , then is it true that the set $\{(a,b)\in \mathbb C^2 : f(a,b)=0\}$ contains a connected subset with more than one point ? If the statement is not in general true , then what happens if we also assume $f$ is homogenous ? ( I only know that the zero set must be uncountable )

Comment: yes unless it's empty (for example if $f(a,b)=1$)

Comment: @mercio : I mentioned $f$ is irreducible so non-unit so non-constant

Answer (score 4):

I have good news for you: given an irreducible polynomial $f\in \mathbb C[x,y]$, the whole of its zero set $$V(f)=\{(a,b)\in \mathbb C^2\vert f(a,b)=0\}\subset \mathbb C^2$$ is already connected  in the topology inherited from $\mathbb C^2$ (in its classical metric topology).
This is a special case of a vastly more general theorem:

**Theorem**
Given an irreducible  algebraic variety $X$ over $\mathbb C$, its associated holomorphic variety $X(\mathbb C)$ is connected in its classical topology.

(The classical topology of $X(\mathbb C)$ is the one it inherits from its local embeddings into $\mathbb C^n$)
This applies to your situation, since your irreducible polynomial $f$ is easily  seen (without invoking the Nullstellensatz!) to define an *irreducible* algebraic variety $X=V(f)$ .

**References**
The Theorem is proved in [Shafarevich's Basic Algebraic Geometry](https://books.google.de/books/about/Basic_algebraic_geometry.html?id=jZW2-UW4DkMC&hl=fr) , volume 2, Chapter VII, Section 2, Theorem 1, page 127.

The irreducibility assertion is in [Fulton's online notes](http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~wfulton/CurveBook.pdf), Chapter 1, Section 1.6, Corollary 3, page 9.